# HL client using fabric gateway API

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, gateway

I am trying to migrate my app from Fabric SDK to Fabric gateway and writing a sample POC for it. As i am already connecting to blockchain using fabric java sdk I already have certificates,keys and necessary security stuff set up.In gateway, we create wallets holding the user identities and pass it to Gateway object to access the network. I am trying to figure out how do I got ahead and instantiate Wallet object by using the existing keys and certificates I have already.For e.g If I have to use FileSystemStore wallet as below which will later be used while connecting to gateway connection.

```
WalletStore walletStore = new FileSystemWalletStore(walletDirectory);   
WalletImpl wallet = new WalletImpl(walletStore);
```

Any pointers would help.I am using java to write a client app.

Answer (score 0):

Using the mspId, an X509 certificate and the private key of your user, you can create an X509Identity, put that into a wallet instance and supply that to your gateway builder:

```
Identity identity = Identities.newX509Identity(<msp_id>, <x509_certificate>, <private_key>);

Wallet wallet = Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(<path_to_wallet>);
wallet.put(<enrollment_id>, identity);

Gateway.Builder gatewayBuilder = Gateway.createBuilder();
Gateway gateway = gatewayBuilder
                        .identity(wallet, <enrollment_id>)
                        .networkConfig(<path_to_connection_profile>)
                        .discovery(<service_discovery_option>)
                        .connect();
```